# Combine various temporal criteria to filter rows

Tags: postgresql, datetime, temporal-tables

I am trying to query a database table with some filters. I have a form through which a user will create query attributes:
[image: Form for User]
When user will click on search it will pass such values:

```
 {camera_id: "9879"
, from_date: "2015/05/15"
, to_date: "2016/08/15"
, interval: "120"
, schedule: "{"Monday":["3:0-4:0"],"Tuesday":["1:30-3:30"]
             ,"Wed…":["0:0-3:0"],"Saturday":[],"Sunday":["1:0-3:0"]}"}
```

`interval` has one of these names and values:

```
"All", "0"
"1 Frame Every 1 min", "1"
"1 Frame Every 5 min", "5"
...
"1 Frame Every hour", "60"
...
"1 Frame Every 24 hours", "1440"
```

For example: `"1 Frame every 1 min"`. If 5 rows in `snapshots` have been taken within 1 min, the query shall only return the first.

`schedule` is being sent by using the `FullCalendar` jquery plugin. Meaning:

```
Day: Monday,    Time: 03:00 AM to 04:00 AM
Day: Tuesday,   Time: 01:30 AM to 03:30 AM
...
```

Table `snapshots`:

```
  snapshot_id integer
, camera_id   integer
, created_at  timestamp
```

I want to select rows passing the filters. Temporal filters apply to `created_at`. I want rows between `from_date` and `to_date`, considering the `schedule`, and only get the first row per `interval`.

Comment: Please show example data and the expected output for a given set of conditions.  The details about how the latter is derived from the frontend input are not that useful.

Comment: Looks like a follow-up to this previous question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129052/filter-created-at-and-count-distinct-minutes

Comment: yeah but last time i was unclear manytimes this time am clear about question, is it possible?

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite your question completely. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yess exactly thats what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic solution to retrieve only the first row per interval would be to

1. Generate time series using `from_date`, `to_date`and `interval` with `generate_series()`.
2. Join to (pre-selected) main table thereby forming 1 group per interval.
3. Use `DISTINCT ON` to get the first per group.

   - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

For simpler parameter handling I wrapped the query in a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_snapshots(_camera_id int
                                     , _from_date timestamp
                                     , _to_date   timestamp
                                     , _interval  interval = '0 min')
  RETURNS SETOF snapshots AS
$func$
BEGIN
IF _interval > '0 min' THEN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (i) s.* 
   FROM  (
      SELECT *
      FROM   snapshots
      WHERE  created_at >= _from_date
      AND    created_at <  _to_date    -- exclude upper bound?
      ) s
   JOIN   generate_series(_from_date
                        , _to_date - _interval  -- adjust upper bound
                        , _interval) i ON s.created_at >= i
                                      AND s.created_at <  i + _interval
   ORDER  BY i, created_at;

ELSE  -- no interval, return all rows
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT *
   FROM   snapshots
   WHERE  created_at >= _from_date
   AND    created_at <  _to_date
   ORDER  BY created_at;
END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_snapshots(
        _camera_id := '9879'
      , _from_date := '2015-05-15 00:00'
      , _to_date   := '2016-08-15 00:00'
      , _interval  := '120 min');
```

I ignored the additional filter `schedule`. Add that yourself. I would extract all intervals from the json document and add OR'ed `WHERE` conditions. Either use the SQL `OVERLAPS` operator or the [overlap operator `&&` for range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html). More:

- [2 B-tree indices OR 1 GiST index on tsrange -- which will perform better?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59074/2-b-tree-indices-or-1-gist-index-on-tsrange-which-will-perform-better/59083#59083)
- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305292/939860)

Also consider my answer to your previous question:

- [Filter created_at and count distinct minutes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129052/filter-created-at-and-count-distinct-minutes/129060#129060)